# Multiple path aliases based on taxonomy term

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have taxonomy terms from A-Z and each article can belong to multiple terms.

for an example, when I create a new article, I have a multi select list for terms. Therefore a particular node should work for multiple URLs.

example.com/categories/a/planning 
example.com/categories/g/planning 
example.com/categories/s/planning

Please let me know if this can be achieved using a contributed module or can it be built with a custom module?

Comment: It's a very easy task to create aliases. Do you need to create aliases during node save? Do they already exist? How does a user get to each alias? Should the URL be built for the user via form (or some other dynamic method)??

Comment: Hi, I know the process of creating aliases. My problem is when a node is assigned to 2 or more categories, the URL becomes example.com/categories/a-g/planning instead creating 2 alises, one for example.com/categories/a/planning and another for example.com/categories/g/planning

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.
After installing the pathauto module, please configure the path of `article` content type from here `admin/config/search/path/patterns`.

**Note:** 
To use pattern require [token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module. 
Then use like following pattern:

```
categories/[node:field-token-of-term-reference-field]/[node:title]
```

Comment: I have used pathauto and tokens within the site. However, as I mentioned earlier my problem is when a node belongs to 2 or more categories. Then the alias becomes example.com/categories/a-g/planning instead of creating multiple aliases such as one for example.com/categories/a/planning and one for example.com/categories/g./planning